# Does CoD: Modern Warfare mix players from every console (PS3, Xbox 360, PC)?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I bought CoD: Modern Warfare not long ago (pretty late to the party), and while I do find it enjoyable, the online multiplayer experience has mostly been me dying over and over again.

I somehow feel my opponents have superhuman abilities. I can't turn and aim as fast and accurately as my death view shows my opponents do (then again, maybe I just suck).

So, my question is, does the online multiplayer mix console gamers with PC gamers (whom I think have an advantage in terms of control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are *no* games that do this** - [Microsoft will not allow it](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/ms-killed-pc-xbox-cross-platform-play).

However, PS3 has no such restriction - (some) game developers are *allowed* to make games cross-platform compatible between PC and PS3.

To date, the only game I know of that does this is [Portal 2](http://ps3.ign.com/articles/114/1144372p1.html), though <strike>the upcoming [CS:GO](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/08/26/counter-strike-global-offensive-to-have-cross-play-for-ps3-pc/) will also.</strike>
**[Edit]**: Valve [changed their minds](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/03/05/counter-strike-global-offensive-loses-cross-play/).

Comment: A competitive game with PC vs console players? Valve sure does like a challenge. I predict disaster and auto kicks based on one's platform.

Answer (score 5):

No it does not.

It'd be very unfair to pair them up, for example, on a console, they quite often use aimbots built into the game to help the player hit the heads etc... but on PCs those will get you banned. So if they were to mix it, you can see how it'd run into problems.

All that to say if you play on console you should be pitted against other console players (I believe) it's the same console types even (PS3 vs PS3, xbox vs xbox...).

Comment: I suspect Sony would not appreciate people playing a 360 game alongside people playing a PS3 game, and vice-versa. That would give extra value to a competitor's product. I can't think of any games that allow cross-console play like that.

Comment: @Mag I don't think Sony can have that much influence over a game, or else it wouldn't allow any PS3 games to be made at all in any other consoles.

Comment: @Kenji: It can however influence the online aspect of the game. It does control the service, as does MS for its service.

Comment: @Kenji they aren't saying that the games can't exist on both consoles, but you won't ever see any multiplayer games on consoles that connect with players from other console brands (PS3 to Xbox 360 doesn't happen or vice versa). The two online services are completely different and separate and i would wager they would never mix the two services.

Comment: Hm, well they control the *access* to the game's server (via PSN), but it's beyond their control what the game does from there. Kinda like OpenID and Facebooks login service I'd say. And I'd say it does make some business sense to mix both console players. It's another entry barrier down and good advertisement. People won't go with a provider that penalizes you by restricting who you play with if there's a freer alternative. Then again, there isn't one so far.

Comment: @Kenji I have firsthand experience that Sony/MS do very much have full control over what your game does and does not do. You cannot release a game for their consoles without their approval, and they will reject you for doing things that are against the (very strict) rules.

Comment: @Mag I have to differ yet again, now with evidence. http://www.joystiq.com/2011/01/18/portal-2-on-ps3-features-cross-platform-chat-multiplayer-and-a/ It seems it *does* make business sense.

Comment: @Kensai You misunderstand me. Mac/PC-to-PS3 compatibility is fine. I was talking specifically about 360-to-PS3 compatibility. In order to get that working, you'd have to get Microsoft and Sony to cooperate with one another. Since they are direct competitors, that's difficult. Microsoft doesn't have nearly as tight a grip on the PC market as they do on the 360 market.

Comment: Actually, Microsoft found that allowing cross-platform play was not fair for the console players, not the other way around.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Last time i looked up this subject, i found microsoft had tested an interface to mix their live services (PC and XBOX) however cancelled the project due to the advantage of pc players versus console players in FPS.

But at the moment, no mixing is done even though it would be nice if microsoft and sony one day just hook up their networks. i believe the amount of people buying an xbox/ps3 to play with their friends would balance out for them.

I doubt it will ever happen though.

Comment: Well, if a game is cooperative, there's no problem in mixing PS3 and PC it seems. http://www.joystiq.com/2011/01/18/portal-2-on-ps3-features-cross-platform-chat-multiplayer-and-a/

Answer (score 0):

**No.** It is not possible to play with players on different platforms in Call of Duty: Modern Warfare. (COD4)